# return regex variable without knowing variable names

Tags: python, regex

I have this line of code:

`hdfs_regex = re.compile(r'\s+(?P<unmatched>\d+)\s+\/\s+(?P<total>\d+)')`

I run through a file and use:

`results = re.search(hdfs_regex, line)`

to look for the portion in the `line` that matches my regex. Upon match, is there a way to return each found matched regex variable?

Is there away to return ever found `group` without knowing the regex variable name?

Pseudocode would might look something like this

`grouped_val = [i for i in results.grouped()]`

where `results.grouped()` is an iterable that I can use to retrieve the found value without knowing the variable name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`groups()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.groups) that return a tuple containing all the subgroups of the matched patterns :

```
>>> m = re.search(r"(\d+)\.?(\d+)?", "24.13244")
>>> m.groups()
('24', '13244')
```

> **groups([default])**
>   Return a tuple containing all the subgroups of the match, from 1 up to however many groups are in the pattern. The default argument is used for groups that did not participate in the match; it defaults to None. (Incompatibility note: in the original Python 1.5 release, if the tuple was one element long, a string would be returned instead. In later versions (from 1.5.1 on), a singleton tuple is returned in such cases.)

Comment: Just what I needed thanks! will accept when allowed!